Software Updater fails to update 22.04LTS to 24.04LTS
Every time I run Software Updater it offers an upgrade to 24.04LTS. Even if I click on the “Update Now” box, all that happens is that the window, and the application, closes. I also get prompt boxes every now and then informing me that 24.04LTS is available, and I have 22.04LTS. I know, thanks. Click on the Update box and the same thing happens: the window closes, and nothing else.

Open a terminal. Run sudo apt update. Review the output. Your 22.04 system must be 100% updated (upgradeable = 0, kept-back  = 0) for a release-upgrade to 24.04 to work.

This happens:
~$ sudo apt update
...
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libasound2-plugins/oldstable 1:1.2.2-dmo4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.2.6-1]
libmng2/oldstable 1:2.0.3-dmo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.3+dfsg-3]
ng2/oldstable 1:2.0.3-dmo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.3+dfsg-3]

Please don't add new information to comments. As you see, they are unformatted and unreadable. Edit your question instead.
